# which is better for sending contact to server WBXML or VCARD?

Tags: c, xml, vcf-vcard, wbxml

We are generating WBXML file containing the phone contact and want to send to server.How we send to server and decode WBXML file at server side.Actually i have to send phone contact to server using sync-ml protocol and don't want to use v-card(.vcf file).I think if we send WBXML file to server and server decode that file and save it.The WBXML file contain all phone contact while if we use v-card we have to generate particular vcf file for every contact.Which is better option for sync, sending WBXML file or vcf file ? we have to implement in c , windows .

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting Microsoft Exchange Server that go for WBXML. By default EAS use WBXML.